# Cucumber-java rerun fail to execute only the failed test

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I have built a cucumber + java + selenium project and i want to add rerun phase in my pipeline.Using @rerun plugin in runner **AllTestRunner.java** i able to create a rerun.txt with only the failed test, and using maven-surefire-plugin, i create a 2nd runner **FailedRunner.java** for executing automatically, the failed test only.

The problem is that **FailedRunner.java** does not execute only the failed tests, but all the test that is configured as feature file in **AllTestRunner.java**.
Any idea why this happens?
Here is my pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
<!--                <configuration>-->
<!--                    <parallel>methods</parallel>-->
<!--                    <threadCount>3</threadCount>-->
<!--                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>-->
<!--                </configuration>-->
            </plugin>
```

and the **ExecuteRunner.java**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/com/bdd/jenkins",
        glue = {"com.bdd.helpers", "com.bdd.steps"},
        tags= "not @Fail", //not @ignore
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json", "rerun:target/rerun.txt"}
)
public class ExecuteRunner {
}
```

and the **FailedRunner.java**

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "@target/rerun.txt",
        glue = {"com.bdd.helpers", "com.bdd.steps"},
        plugin = {"pretty","html:target/cucumberRerun", "json:target/cucumberRerun.json"}
)
public class FailedRunner {
}
```

At the logs i see the followings:

```
Running com.pollfish.bdd.runners.ExecuteRunner
20:21:39,519 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
20:21:39,519 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
2
....
@batch1 @Test1
Scenario: Create questionnaire adding targeting and send for approval # src/test/resources/com/bdd/jenkins/migrated/CreateSurvey.feature:22
20:21:41.179 [main] INFO  com.bdd.steps.Hooks - Every test start from home page.
2
```

and

```
Running com.pollfish.bdd.runners.FailedRunner
02:41:09.170 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener
...
@batch1 @Test1
Scenario: Create questionnaire adding targeting and send for approval # src/test/resources/com/bdd/jenkins/migrated/CreateSurvey.feature:22
02:41:09.283 [main] INFO  com.bdd.steps.Hooks - Every test start from home page.
```

And **rerun.txt** contains

```
file:src/test/resources/com/bdd/jenkins/migrated/QuestionnaireADL.feature:6:44:54:84
file:src/test/resources/com/bdd/jenkins/migrated/Recurring.feature:12:43:60
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the culprit. Because i run it via maven build tool, with the following command : `mvn clean test -Dcucumber.features=src/test/resources/features`, it looks that in **FailedRunner.java** even though we set the special rerun feature file, and because command line argument overrides class defined parameter, executes again all the tests.
Works as design , i would say